# linux password contains carriage return (^M or 0x0D or \r): how to send password through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, carriage-return

I have a password for a user in linux that contains text and carriage return. I am trying to connect using ssh (with or without sshpass) but I noticed that ssh doesnt send carriage return in password, just the text.

Is there a way to send the password with CR (an option in ssh or something else) ?

Comment: \n maybe......?

Comment: no. You don't want to do this. Just change the password to something reasonable. @FranciscoTapia: No, it is newline and @beezy wants carriage-return, which is `\r`. But it is certainly *not* expanded in the password prompt.

Comment: :o ok, to do logins and send command remotely i use python paramiko. could be a good option.

Comment: hmm, I'm pretty sure the OpenSSH _server_ also forbids carriage-return in passwords

Comment: a password with a CR.. is he just trying to test the skills of the IT department, and ssh? If he stumped grawity or beaten ssh, then he definitely wins

Answer (score 2):

Expecting every possible password entry system to accept \r is probably expecting too much. I guess you can say it's secure!

In this case I would side-step the problem and authenticate using an SSH key.

Or just change the password. That would work too.